# Django or C++ web framework (for example, WT) for huge project in the web

Tags: c++, django, qt, web-frameworks, wt

I'm trying to find a suitable web framework for a huge project. I'm looking for a web framework. Executive power is high, but I have no experience working with both on the web. [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) is easy to work with.

Would I use Django or C++? If a C++ based web framework is available I would prefer it.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746309/which-is-the-best-c-web-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked with Django for a site and it was great. It does many things that we say are "chores" by itself, so it's helpful.

Comment: is good for huge project? for example social network ?

Comment: to tell the truth, my site wasn't a huge project. But python is so cool for programming high-level projects. (from the developer side) About the performance have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810540/django-for-social-networking