# Django error: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1) when iterating queryset

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset

I've been working with django for a few months now, and normally a simple google search takes care of any of my problems (usually with a link to SO). I have finally come across something that I can't find a solution to and is completely baffling.

General error information:

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    localhost:8000/switch/1
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:
invalid syntax (, line 1)
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py in parse, line 37
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3

Relevant View code

```
interfaces = Interface.objects.filter(switch=switch)
interfaces = sorted(interfaces, key=lambda x: x.name)
interfaces = sorted(interfaces, key=lambda x: len(x.name))
interface_table = InterfaceTable(interfaces)
```

Relevant Model code

```
class Interface(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = "Network_Builder"

name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
fullname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
switch = models.ForeignKey("Switch", related_name='switch')
physical_state = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True) 
administrator_notes = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)

access_vlan = models.ForeignKey(Vlan, related_name='access_vlan', blank=True, null=True)
native_vlan = models.ForeignKey(Vlan, related_name='native_vlan', blank=True, null=True)

admin_mode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True) 
operational_mode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
admin_encapsulation = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
operational_encapsulation = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

switchport_state = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
negotiation = models.BooleanField(blank=True) 
native_vlan_tagging = models.BooleanField(blank=True)

allowed_vlans_list = ListField(blank=True, null=True)
allowed_vlans_string = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
active_vlans = models.ManyToManyField(Vlan, related_name='active_vlans', blank=True, null=True)
unpruned_vlans = models.ManyToManyField(Vlan, related_name='unpruned_vlans', blank=True, null=True)

protected = models.BooleanField()
unicast_blocked = models.BooleanField()
multicast_blocked = models.BooleanField()
```

Stack Trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/switch/2

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Network_Builder',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django_tables2')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ellis/Projects/Network_Builder/Network_Builder/views/switch/info_views.py" in switch_page
  46.     interfaces = sorted(interfaces, key=lambda x: x.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  87.             self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  301.                     obj = model(*row[index_start:aggregate_start])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  300.                 setattr(self, field.attname, val)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py" in __set__
  34.         obj.__dict__[self.field.name] = self.field.to_python(value)
File "/home/ellis/Projects/Network_Builder/Network_Builder/models/model_fields.py" in to_python
  18.         return ast.literal_eval(value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py" in literal_eval
  49.         node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py" in parse
  37.     return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /switch/2
Exception Value: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)
```

At this line:

```
interfaces = Interface.objects.filter(switch=switch)
```

interfaces is populated with a queryset (observable through pdb), but as soon as I try to do anything to the variable (including printing, iterating, or sorting as seen in the above code), an error is thrown. The completely baffling part is that if I toss the call into a try:except:, the variable "interfaces" is completely usable as it should be.

Has anyone seen anything like this before, or have any insight in how to track down a solution?

Comment: what is the entire stack trace ?

Comment: Just tossed it into the main topic.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't necessarily figure it out. But I was using ast in a custom listfield ([How to create list field in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216162/how-to-create-list-field-in-django)) that was somehow breaking a queryset's iterablility