# Django Model List of Coordinates

Tags: list, django-models, coordinates, points

I want to store a bunch of `lines/paths` in a database (using Django), where each line has a title or other info in the table, along with a list of `(x,y)` coordinates.  What is the best way to store these coordinates?  It seems like a `ManyToManyField` is not fitting, and things like `CharFields` are a waste of space and processing.  How do I add a list of points in the form `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]` to the database or get it back out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create list field in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216162/how-to-create-list-field-in-django)

Comment: the ListField does not support complex types (lists), so this is not a duplicate

Comment: You want to store coordinates. No need for lists, tuples will do.

Comment: I assumed a tuple was a complex type, since it is very nearly a list.  Not true?

Comment: My english is nowhere near good enough to explain you the difference :/. Instead, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/626871/1824222). Basically think of tuples as structuring thingies, and lists as objects with methods and stuff.