# Why there isn't a "ListField" in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-migrations

I have a model that has a `Charfield` (let's name it **advantages**) with a `choices` attribute. After a while, I've decided that this field should be "upgraded" to some kind of `ListField`, since more than one choice can be selected.

From what I have searched, I have two options:

1 - Create a new model, and use a ManyToManyField in the first model referencing this new model. This way, the "multiple select" default field used in admin will be rendered. Life is good.

2- Create a custom field that saves my field as a string with some kind of separator.

These two approaches are summarized in [What is the most efficent way to store a list in the Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110153/what-is-the-most-efficent-way-to-store-a-list-in-the-django-models) and the 2nd approach in more examples: [How to create list field in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216162/how-to-create-list-field-in-django), http://cramer.io/2008/08/08/custom-fields-in-django/, https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1200/, https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1491/

Fact is: I don't want to create another model just to have the `ManyToManyField`. This is a controlled list of choices that I have (and don't want people adding new items) and think that creating a table for this is overkill (although I can create a fixture to this table and not register the model in `admin.py`, so people wouldn't be adding new items. But I don't know how would migrations work when changing these values in fixtures, when in the past I would just chance the **choices** tuple in my model definition).

...and creating a new custom field, I don't know. This seems like problems in the long run since I don't know the implications, problems when upgrading Django, etc.

Why there isn't a built in `ListField`? Which problems do you see in the long run for the two approaches I'm thinking of? I'm planning to do the first but I'm a little lost about migrations.

Comment: Do you mean a `ListField` (Array datatype) ? The issue is with the backend database - Postgres does support a list field, but mysql, sqlite, etc do not.. The future versions of django have a possiblity of including features to more closely support postgres database, so this might indeed be a reality.

Comment: @karthikr I now this is because of backend agnostic features. But a not so 'fast' `ListField ` using the 2nd approach would be nice to have if it was builtin. It doesn't necessarily needs to be an array, but it would *appear* to be, even with some performance issues.

Comment: Because it would violate normalization and never be large enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[django.contrib.postgres has an ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not be willing to create a new table with only the List inside (because it would be "overkill"), but what you are suggesting is to copy/paste the same exact values in **all** the entries of your table, which isn't a good model solution in my opinion.

I'd advise to go for the ManyToMany (or any other implementation doing the trick with another table).