# Django ListField with add and remove

Tags: python, django

The below link specifies how to create a list-field in Django.

[How to create list field in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216162/how-to-create-list-field-in-django)

My question; how to add, remove items to this field? if in case that's possible. I want to be able to add to and remove from this field of a Model's instance afterwards. If not possible please someone suggest me an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `ListField`:

`to_python` function is used to convert database string to python object(here is list)
`get_prep_value` is used to handle python object to string(to store into database next step).
when you call your obj.listfield, such as `a.list`, you'll get a python list, so you could use `a.list.append(val)`, `a.list.insert(0, val)` method to operate, and at last call `a.save()`, `listfield` will do the conversion for you between database and python.

```
class Dummy(models.Model):
    mylist = ListField()

    def insert_to_mylist(self, index, value):
        self.mylist.insert(index, value)
        #self.save()
    def remove_from_mylist(self, value):
        self.mylist.remove(value)
        #self.save()
```

for example:

```
d = Dummy()
d.mylist.insert(0, 'tu')
d.save()

d.mylist.remove('tu')
d.save()

d.insert_to_mylist(0, "tu")
d.save()

d.remove_from_mylist('tu')
d.save()
```

if you want to insert or remove without `.save()`, just add `.save()` to `insert_to_mylist` and `remove_from_mylist` function.

`ListField` is just used to conversion between database and python, so add a remove or insert to it may be difficult. But you can do it in your Model, if many Models need to use this method, just write an `abstract model`.

Answer (score 1):

My way of storing lists in models is by converting them to a string and storing them as TextField.